# Multiple React routers - same path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to React and trying to do the following: 
In my system users have different roles (regular, manager, admin). 
For each role, I use a different Router object. 
Both in my AdminRouter and in my ManagerRouter, I want to have a path to /dashboard, but each will direct to a different component.

```
     <Router>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <AdminRouter path="/dashboard" component={AdminDashboardPage}/>
                <ManagerRouter path="/dashboard" component={ManagerDashboardPage} />
                <Route component={NotFoundPage}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
```

Is it possible to add some logic that will decide (based on the user role) to ignore some router? For example, if the user is Manager, the router will skip all the AdminRouter elements.

Comment: Have you looked in to optional parameters ?                                       <Route path="/to/page/:pathParam?" component={MyPage} />

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your router can't have same rout for two different components, it will always render the first one.

What you can do instead is to make a wrapper component that's going to decide what to render.

For example:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={DashboardWrapper}/>
     <Route component={NotFoundPage}/>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

and in `DashboardWrapper`

```
class DashboardWrapper extends Component {
  ...
  render (){
    const { adminUser } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        {
          adminUser
          ? <AdminDashboard />
          : <ManagerDashboard />
        } 
      </div>
    )
  }
  ...
}
```